# Method overloading in Angular 4 / 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am now working with Angular 4. I have not found any proper solution about method overloading in Angular 2 or 4. Is it possible to implement method overloading in an angular service class? Or I am interested to know details about it. Thanks in advance.

I have just tried to crate **Service** like below but found ***Duplicate function implementation error***

**ApiService.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
 
       constructor() { }

       postCall(url, data, token) { // with three parameters
                 return resultFromServer; }        

       postCall(url, data) { // with two parameters
                return resultFromServer;}          
       }
```

**AuthenticationService.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "app/_services/api.service";
import FunUtils from "app/_helper/utils";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    
    constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

    rest_login_call(userName, password) {
        let data = { username: userName, password: password };
        let url = "http://localhost:8000";
        return this.api.postCall(url, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: It should be 
 `postCall(url, data, token):void`    // with three parameter     

 `postCall(url, data):void`        

{ } ->means blank method.

Comment: Partha Ghiya: sorry I must return response from server in these methods.

Comment: @ShakirAqeel actually in javascript/typescript so far I know method overloading concept is absent. jayakrishnan and monica gave wonderful alternative method to solve the problem. though it solved my problem but it is not the answer. that's why I gave them thanks and upvote. hope I can explain. thanks

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thank you for helping me, in a very polite way.
I deleted my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of overloading methods, make the **token** parameter optional.

```
postCall(url, data, token?) { // with three parameters
             return resultFromServer; 
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: that or use Abstract methods and make component inheritance I guess

Comment: thanks Gounder@ for your good suggestion. It solved my problem for now and you worth plus.

Answer (score 9):

As of TypeScript 1.4, you can typically remove the need for an overload using an optional parameter and union type(if you don't know the type of the param). The above example can be better expressed using:

```
postCall(url: string, data: Object, token?: string | number) {
   return resultFromServer; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is said that typescript is syntactic sugar. Typescript code is transpiled to javascript before execution. Typescript has function overloading functionality with limitations. As given:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads.

But it is good to handle overloading needs with other available options i.e. token as an optional parameter `token?: someType`  As:

**Example For Varying Number of Parameters:**

```
//implementation with three or two parameters
//when you call this function with first two arguments
//i.e postCall(someValue, someValue);
//the third argument will be undefined
//you can write the implentation in if/else block

postCall(url: SomeType, data: SomeType , token?: SomeType) { 

   if (token === undefined) {
      //if token is undefined it means you are calling with two arguments
      //write implementation here for two arguments function call
      return resultFromServer; 
   }

   else {
      //write implementation here for function call with three arguments
      //when you call this function with all three arguments
      //i.e postCall(someValue, someValue, someValue);
      return resultFromServer; 
   } 

}
```

**Example For Varying Types of Parameters:**

You can use union of types i.e.  `someVariable: AType | BType`

```
postCall(someVariable: AType | BType) { 

   if (typeof(someVariable) === AType) {
      //implementation for AType
      return resultFromServer; 
   }
   else if (typeof(someVariable) === BType) {
      //implementation for BType
      return resultFromServer; 
   }
}
```